# New to Python, can't find bug

Tags: python, debugging

I am new to Python (3rd day) and I was just trying to creat a basic Rock, Paper, Scissors. I am seeing a bug that I can't locate in the code and was hoping somebody could help. Here is the output below with the code following:

```
Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!
Player 1 name?b
Player 2 name?s
3
2
1
GO!
Rock, Paper or Scissors?rock
b  threw  rock
s  threw  rock
Draw! Get Ready!.
3
2
1
GO!
Rock, Paper or Scissors?rock
b  threw  rock
s  threw  scissors
b  win.
Rematch?no
Goodbye.
b  win.
Rematch?
```

## After entering "no" for rematch, it is printing "b win." also asking "Rematch?" again. Here is the code below:

```
import time
import random
picks=["rock","paper","scissors"]
answers=["yes","no"]
rock="rock"
paper="paper"
scissors="scissors"
yes="yes"
no="no"
invalid=""
#############################################Defining Functions#########################################################
def rename1():
    global name1
    while True:
        if name1 is invalid:
            name1 = input("Player 1 name?")
        if name1 is not invalid:
            break

def rename2():
    global name2
    while True:
        if name2 is invalid:
            name2 = input("Player 2 name?")
        if name2 is not invalid:
            break

def rematchinvalid():
    global rematch
    while True:
        if rematch not in answers:
            print("Invalid, try again..")
            rematch = input("Rematch?")
        if rematch in answers:
            break

def Rethrow1():
    global P1
    while True:
        if P1 not in picks:
             print("Invalid, try again..")
             P1 = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
        if P1 in picks:
            break

def start():
    print("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GO!")

def RPS():
    global P1
    global P2
    global rematch
    P1 = input("Rock, Paper or Scissors?")
    P2 = random.choice(picks)
    if P1 not in picks:
        Rethrow1()
    battle()
    winner()

def battle():
    print(name1," threw ",P1)
    print(name2," threw ",P2)

def winner():
    global rematch
    if P1 == P2:
        print("Draw! Get Ready!.")
        start()
        RPS()
    if P1 == rock and P2 == scissors:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == rock and P2 == paper:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == rock:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == paper:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == rock:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == scissors:
            print(name2," win.")
    rematch = input("Rematch?")
    if rematch not in answers:
        rematchinvalid()
    replay()

def replay():
    if rematch == yes:
        start()
        RPS()
    if rematch == no:
        print("Goodbye.")
################################################Game Start##############################################################
print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
name1 = input("Player 1 name?")
if name1 is invalid:
    rename1()
name2 = input("Player 2 name?")
if name2 is invalid:
    rename2()
start()
RPS()
```

Also, if you have any recommendations on how to clean up the code, that would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `is` for equality. `is` is for identity...the two items are exactly the same object.  Use `==` for equality.  `is` sometimes seems to work because the Python implementation may optimize common objects like empty strings and small numbers, but it will bite you.  Try it with `x=1000;y=123+877;x==y;x is y`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your function `winner`:

```
def winner():
    global rematch
    if P1 == P2:
        print("Draw! Get Ready!.")
        start()
        RPS()
    if P1 == rock and P2 == scissors:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == rock and P2 == paper:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == rock:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == paper:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == rock:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == scissors:
            print(name2," win.")
    rematch = input("Rematch?")
    if rematch not in answers:
        rematchinvalid()
    replay()
```

When there is a tie, you print *Draw! Get Ready!.*, call `start()`, call `RPS()`, then what? Then, instead of exiting the function, you let the control flowed right into the code below, which displayed the winner name one more time, then asked for rematch one more time before exiting the function. I leave it up to you to fix it.

As for recommendation: please do not use global variables.

## Update

Here is some suggestion to eliminate global variables: pass information into functions and return information from function. For example, here is a way to eliminate the global variable `rematch`. This variable is first used in `winner()` and then passed to `replay()`. Also, `rematchinvalid()` get the user's input into this variable and pass it back to `winner`, so the information flow for rematch is:

```
rematchinvalid <==> winner ==> replay
```

With that in mind, we can fix `rematchinvalid()` as such:

```
def rematchinvalid(rematch):
    # Remove the global statement here
    while True:
        if rematch not in answers:
            print("Invalid, try again..")
            rematch = input("Rematch?")
        if rematch in answers:
            break
    return rematch  # Return rematch to the caller
```

As for `winner()`, we will receive information from `rematchinvalid()` and pass it on to `replay()`:

```
def winner():
    # Remove global statement
    if P1 == P2:
        print("Draw! Get Ready!.")
        start()
        RPS()
        return  # Fix for your problem
    if P1 == rock and P2 == scissors:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == rock and P2 == paper:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == rock:
            print(name2," win.")
    if P1 == scissors and P2 == paper:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == rock:
            print(name1," win.")
    if P1 == paper and P2 == scissors:
            print(name2," win.")
    rematch = input("Rematch?")
    if rematch not in answers:
        rematch = rematchinvalid(rematch)  # Get the valid rematch
    replay(rematch)  # Pass rematch to replay
```

Finally, for replay, we can accept `rematch` as a parameter:

```
def replay(rematch):
    if rematch == yes:
        start()
        RPS()
    if rematch == no:
        print("Goodbye.")
```

That should take care of `rematch`. You can apply this method to eliminate other variables as well.

Comment: Thanks! figured it out! any tips on getting around globals?

Comment: Exactly! The control flow for the draw case is not something I saw immediately. Just set a flag to exit it from the function. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is primarily a small logic error. While loops with a true condition are generally a bad practice. The crux is that you can rewrite `rematchinvalid()` like this and still be logically equivalent to what you wanted to achieve.

```
def rematchinvalid():
    global rematch
    while rematch not in answers:
            print("Invalid, try again..")
            rematch = input("Rematch?")
```

Furthermore, try implementing this for the other functions as well. Another thing I noticed -

```
Rock, Paper, or Scissors?paper
a  threw  paper
b  threw  paper
Draw! Get Ready!.
3
2
1
GO!
Rock, Paper or Scissors?paper
a  threw  paper
b  threw  rock
a  win.
Rematch?no
Goodbye.
a  win.
Rematch?no
Goodbye.
Goodbye.
a  win.
Rematch?no
Goodbye.
Goodbye.
a  win.
Rematch?no
Goodbye.
```

If you get a draw you should set a flag to exit the function. Otherwise you end up with something like this in the output!

Answer (score 0):

> if you have any recommendations on how to clean up the code, that would be appreciated

```
codes = {'rock':0, 'paper':1, 'scissors':2}
...
def winner():
    outcome = (codes[P1]-codes[P2])%3
    if outcome == 0:
        # it's a draw
    elif outcome == 1:
        # player 1 wins
    else:
        # player2 wins
```